# configure temp aws cli user still existing a default cli user

Tags: amazon-web-services, config, aws-cli, temp

How can I configure a temporary AWS-CLI user if I already have a default user in the `.aws/` path ??? if I could create a temp user, I could test my task without interfering default user !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add temp user as follows:

```sh
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<your AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID >
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<your AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>
export AWS_REGION=<your AWS_REGION>
```

When you set these values, you will be able to see similar like these:

```
{
    "Account": "2*********4", 
    "UserId": "A*****************V", 
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::275*******04:user/s3ba*****ser"
}
```

Once you are done, do the rest :

```sh
unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
unset AWS_REGION
```

Comment: this is useful in a bash script in a e.g. CICD pipeline. When working on your PC, a much more pleasant experience is with **awsp** (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use profile as below:

`$ aws ec2 describe-instances --profile user1`

Have a look at the aws documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS CLI [named profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html):

1. Create a new profile called `temp`, provide your temporary CLI user's credentials:

```sh
$ aws configure --profile temp
AWS Access Key ID [None]: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: yyyyyyyyyyyyy
Default region name [None]: eu-central-1
Default output format [None]: json
```

2. Use the newly created profile:

```sh
$ aws s3 ls --profile temp
```

---

Specifying `--profile temp` with each AWS call is not that handy, so consider either of these:

- Specify a profile in an environment variable called `AWS_PROFILE`:

```
$ export AWS_PROFILE=temp
$ aws s3 ls

$ export AWS_PROFILE=another-profile
$ aws s3 ls
```

- Use a profile switcher tool like [awsp](https://github.com/antonbabenko/awsp). With it switching profiles (users/roles) is as easy as:

```sh
$ awsp temp
$ aws s3 ls

$ awsp another-profile
$ awsho
$ aws s3 ls
```

The good thing about `awsp` is it supports auto-complete and you can easily switch between profiles even without memorizing your profile names. If you want to check the current profile, use:

```sh
$ awswho
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                    temp              env    ['AWS_PROFILE', 'AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE']
access_key     ****************DHGY             shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ****************O2pq             shared-credentials-file
    region                eu-central-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```